# PHP sessions default timeout

Tags: php, session, timeout, default

Do PHP sessions timeout by default - ie without any coding on my part would a user eventually be "logged out" after some time of inactivity?

Comment: Thanks for all those. I wanted a little more straight forward answer hence the question! - upvoted

Comment: Amusing how all the answers mention "20 minutes" and "1440 seconds" and no one bothered to notice that 1440 seconds is in fact 24 minutes.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

It depends on the server configuration or the relevant directives [session.gc_maxlifetime](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) in `php.ini`.

Typically the default is 24 minutes (1440 seconds), but your webhost may have altered the default to something else.

Comment: Would like to know why 1440 sec are default? ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/37176824/57091

Comment: Is it 1440 seconds after creation or after last activity ?

Comment: switch to 10800 (3h), connect, no activity during more than 2 hours, then test with click a link… it works

Answer (score 20):

You can change it in you php-configuration on your webserver.
Search in `php.ini` for

`session.gc_maxlifetime()`
The value is set in Seconds.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, that's usually happens after 1440s (24 minutes)

Comment: @Mani When is 1440 seconds 20 minutes?

Answer (score 6):

http://php.net/session.gc-maxlifetime

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
(1440 seconds = 24 minutes)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can set the session time out in php.ini. The default value is 1440 seconds

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440

; NOTE: If you are using the subdirectory option for storing session files
;       (see session.save_path above), then garbage collection does *not*
;       happen automatically.  You will need to do your own garbage
;       collection through a shell script, cron entry, or some other method.
;       For example, the following script would is the equivalent of
;       setting session.gc_maxlifetime to 1440 (1440 seconds = 24 minutes):
;          find /path/to/sessions -cmin +24 -type f | xargs rm
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes typically, a session will end after 20 minutes in PHP.

Comment: Do you mean 20 minutes of inactivity ?? or even if the user is active and keeping some sort of requests tot he site will the session expire ?

Comment: @rammanoj 20 minutes of inactivity.

Comment: 1440 seconds is the default which is actually 24 minutes.