# session.gc_maxlifetime : 1440 seconds

Tags: php, session, garbage-collection

**Findings :**

I have done some research on PHP Session and came accross the `session.gc_maxlifetime` value of `1440` seconds.

I've read on [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#107990) that the `maximum value` of `session.gc_maxlifetime` is `65535`.

**Questions :**

1. Is it possible to set my maxlifetime to more than 65535 seconds?
2. Why is the session value 1440?
3. What happens if we increase the session maxlifetime to more than 65535 seconds. the server configuration doesn't support this?

Comment: I've edited your question to fix the formatting. The back ticks ("`") should only be used to mark code, not for emphasis.

Comment: No, the limit isn't  65535 seconds, but it depends on where you're storing your session data... for example, memcache has a limit of 60*60*24*30 seconds (30 days or 2592000 seconds)

Comment: For q2, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703363/why-is-the-standard-session-lifetime-24-minutes-1440-seconds