# Php Session Variables Destroyed Without Instruction For This

Tags: php, session

I just use Session Variables in my code. I do not start any activity with cookies. I just do session_start() and do the manipulation of the variables.
But at the end of some time (about 30 minutes) the session goes down. If I do print_r ($ _ SESSION) the session is in void.

I've tried set session.gc_maxlifetime to 7200 (2 hours), but the session is destroyed in less than 30 minutes again.

How can I resolve this? It's normal? Should the session not only be destroyed if I close the browser or give the statement/instruction to session_destroy?

Comment: As the default lifetime is 24 mins. I would guess that you have changed the wrong `php.ini` file. There are normally 2 one for use of PHP under Apache and one for the CLI. Do a quick page with just `<?php phpinfo();?>` and check where your real `php.ini` file is located and make sure you are changing the right one

Comment: Moreover, in the `phpinfo()` output, you can actually see what the configured value for `session.gc_maxlifetime` is under the `session` section.

Comment: After phpinfo():


[PHP Version 7.1.7], 
[Server API => LiteSpeed V6.11],
[Loaded Configuration File => /opt/alt/php71/etc/php.ini],
[Additional .ini files parsed => /opt/alt/php71/link/conf/alt_php.ini],
[session.cookie_lifetime => 0],
[session.gc_maxlifetime => 7200]

Comment: But session still down after 24 minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default timeout is 24 minutes.

Other than php.ini, you can change it in code. You could try this:

```
// server should keep session data for AT LEAST 1 hour
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600);

// each client should remember their session id for EXACTLY 1 hour
session_set_cookie_params(3600);

session_start(); // ready to go!
```

from this answer: [How to change the session timeout in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311320/how-to-change-the-session-timeout-in-php)

---

An article on it:

https://bytes.com/topic/php/insights/889606-setting-timeout-php-sessions

which gives code that I've adapted to 2 hours.

```
session_start();
$timeout = 7200; // Number of seconds until it times out.

// Check if the timeout field exists.
if(isset($_SESSION['timeout'])) {
    // See if the number of seconds since the last
    // visit is larger than the timeout period.
    $duration = time() - (int)$_SESSION['timeout'];
    if($duration > $timeout) {
        // Destroy the session and restart it.
        session_destroy();
        session_start();
    }
}

// Update the timout field with the current time.
$_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
```

---

php.net page on it:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Other stack answers verify this (some highly rated):

[PHP sessions default timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904105/php-sessions-default-timeout)
[How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes)

Comment: So i must put "ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600);" in every page where a i have session_start() ? And before the session_start() ?

Like this: <?php ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600); session_start(); ?>

Comment: have a read of my last link, it's good information there. Specifically, I would simply include it in your php header file.

Answer (score 0):

Session variables are meant to hold information until the browser is closed. I am not quite sure what you want to achieve in your project, since you have not posted any code. 
Something simple like not putting `session_write_close();` at the end of your php script or `session_start()` at the very beginning, before any html tags could be messing your code.

Comment: I just want that the session do not destroy with no instruction for this or close the browser . And what i verify is that the session blows away after a while without instrution for this . Taking into account that I do not use cookies . I don't need any code to show my doubt . I only use session_start() in every page and a symply session vars to control if the user is logged in or not ...