Session Timeout Issue in CodeIgniter 4
I'm working on a CodeIgniter 4 project using the Shield authentication library. I've encountered an issue where user sessions are logging out after a short period of time, even though I've extended the session expiration time.
I modified the sessionExpiration setting in Config/App.php to a longer duration
public $sessionExpiration = 7200; // 2 hours

However, the session still expires much sooner than the set expiration time.
Has anyone else faced a similar issue with CodeIgniter 4 Shield? Are there additional configurations or steps I might be missing to ensure the session lasts as expected?

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904105/php-sessions-default-timeout . Edit php.ini -> session.gc_maxlifetime = 7200

Following are some configurations you might need to check:
PHP Session Configuration:
session.gc_maxlifetime = 7200
session.cookie_lifetime = 7200

Session Driver Configuration:
public $sessionDriver = 'CodeIgniter\Session\Handlers\FileHandler';
public $sessionSavePath = WRITEPATH . 'session';


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
