# whole page not loading with high server load, how do I fix?

Tags: php, html, linux, server

it is a php document that only has 2 variables that are hard-coded.  It is a simple splash website that lets customers read about a product and lets them click to the actual product page.  When I send 2000-4000 clicks within a 4-5 hour period the page doesn't load all the way because the high load!  I do not have SSH access, only FTP.  Anything I can do here?

Comment: Upgrade your server.

Comment: Your server is maxxing out on its hardware and can't process that much in time.

Comment: To be honest though you don't need to upgrade your server until real traffic is maxing it out not simulated traffic.

Comment: this is real traffic, real clicks

Comment: You said -you- were sending the clicks. Thats simulating real traffic. It's not actually 2000 different people. When you get 2000 unique visitors in a 5 hour time frame you'll probably make enough money to upgrade anyway. Assuming its profit based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah if you are using sessions and the default time out is left as is, it will fill up your memory on the server and slow right down, set your session timeout value to a low number.

Which can be done with the info from here:
[How to change the session timeout in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311320/how-to-change-the-session-timeout-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

There could be two possibilities:

a) since you have not SSH access I'll assume you're on a shared server, and if that's the case then 2000+ page loads for your site may be too much. You'd have to upgrade your hosting plan.

b) Too many session files for the server to handle. the server may be creating many sessions files as time passes and it keeps receiving more and more requests. To delete the sessions file you'd need SSH access or have the server admin do it for you.

If your server can't deal with 500+ requests an hour then you'd be better off just getting a better hosting plan.

Servers are not limitless, and normally, even higher grade private, self-managed machines, tend to be somewhat slow.