# How to change PHP session time in this code?

Tags: php, session, session-timeout

I am trying to change the session time in my login code, and here is the code I want to change the session time in:

```
<?php
if(session_id()==='')
{
session_start();
}
if(!(isset($_SESSION['status']) && $_SESSION['status'] == "logged_in"))
{
die("sorry, you must be logged in to view this page");
} else {
?>
```

How would I go about changing the session time?
Also, if you can't change the session time in this, is there any code that can replace this and still work the same?

Comment: have you tried changing the session time in the php.ini file? Using PHP code, you could do something like this: ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600);

Comment: `session_id()` must be at the top of *every* page when you want to use sessions. Not just when there is no session ID.

So

    `if(session_id()==='')
    {
    session_start();
    }`

should just be `session_start();`

Comment: Have you look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311320/how-to-change-the-session-timeout-in-php?rq=1 ?

Comment: I am wanting to change the session for an exclusive page, not just the login page

Comment: does it have to be a session? maybe you could do it in a cookie. as cookies life cycle can be edited easily.

Answer (score 0):

You may try session_cache_expire

```
session_cache_expire(30);
$cache_expire = session_cache_expire();
```

or [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes)