# How to terminate PHP session on windows close?

Tags: php, mysql, session, simpleusers

I use SimpleUsers Class and created a database-based login system.
[Here is SimpleUsers on Github](https://github.com/Repox/SimpleUsers)

Here is my question:
How to terminate PHP session on windows close? When the windows closed the session for logged in user is open yet. How can I close it?
I tried to use

```
session_set_cookie_params(0);
```

But it was not helpful.
Please help me.

Comment: This might help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311320/how-to-change-the-session-timeout-in-php

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by "windows" you mean tab of the browser/window of web browser.

Simple answear is: you can't unless user requests. You can try some kind of javascript code with "onclose" method that will send request to your site to close session.
**Cons** of this method is when someone have 2 tabs and at last one is closed, he will be logged out

You should only destroy sessions only when someone hits Logout button.

*Edit to comments*

If you want to secure (bind) session to IP you may want to store in `$_SESSION` IP of user who started session and terminate session if IP changes

```
if($_SESSION['user_ip'] !== $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']){
    // do the code to terminate session.
}
```

Comment: No, your session is automatically cleared when you close your browser.

Comment: On browser side, Yes. On server side it still exists.

Comment: But the question is actually, is it using cookie or session.

Comment: Oh thanks for your answer. What about user IP change?? My purpose is how to terminate the session on client IP change?

Comment: You want to secure it so somone does not steal session id?

Comment: What is $_SESSION['user_ip'] defined? @Gacek