# How to change the session time out in Phalcon Framework

Tags: php, session, phalcon

How to change the default session time in phalcon framework without changing the php.ini file. I am using the below code for starting session in phalcon framework. Any suggestion is most welcome.

```
$di->setShared('session', function() {
            $session = new SessionAdapter();
            $session->start();
            return $session;
        });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There currently isn't a way of doing this in Phalcon itself, you can however try this:

```
$di->setShared('session', function() {

    // Set the max lifetime of a session with 'ini_set()' to one hour
    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600);
    session_set_cookie_params(3600);

    // Start session with Phalcon
    $session = new SessionAdapter();
    $session->start();
    return $session;
});
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311320/how-to-change-the-session-timeout-in-php) question for more information