# Modify session to keep users logged in

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

When I close the browser and open it again, I always have to re-enter my credentials to login. I am guessing I need to change the cookie lifetime and also the gc_maxlifetime. Since this will be used only locally security isn't my main concern. All the payment go via a complete seperate system and no confidential customer data will be used.

I am guessing I need to modify the code in the link below, but I am uncertain how to do so.

Would anyone please help me?

https://github.com/tastyigniter/TastyIgniter/blob/master/system/libraries/Session/Session.php

Comment: We like it when you put the code in the question. No one likes clicking links. Just a thought.

Comment: I thought about it, but it's so God damn long...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311320/how-to-change-the-session-timeout-in-php