# convert array product was seen by user from session to cookie in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm have a code show another product was seen in single product page.
my idea : save id of posts to array by session:
 
Then using loop or foreach to show title, img, link ...etc...

MY CODE

```
session_start();

    $_SESSION['id'] = get_the_ID();
     $cart = array (
        'id' => $_SESSION['id'],
    );

    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $cart; // array id
```

But, when user closed browser. all data not save.
And i want convert session to Cookie to save for one month.
How to change for the right ways.
Please help to the idea for this Solution .

Thankyou all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to change default session timeout, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311320/how-to-change-the-session-timeout-in-php)

But i would suggest to use a cookie instead:
to set a cookie use the [setcookie](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) function, and do something like that:

```
 setcookie('cart', $cart ,mktime().time()+60*60*24*30);
```

It would set a cookie with your cart, and set the expire time to 30 days