# Modification session delay in PHP

Tags: php, session, silex

Do I want delete the time of the session delay in PHP, How I can do it?

I did it by two methods but it doesn't work.

**Method 1:**

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SessionServiceProvider(), array(
  'session.storage.options' => array(
      'cookie_lifetime' => 36000,
      'cookie_httponly' => false,
      'gc_maxlifetime' => 37000
  ),
 )
);
```

**Method 2:**

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SessionServiceProvider());
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8311400/4248328

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the session timeout in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311320/how-to-change-the-session-timeout-in-php)