# While uploading large files session is timed out

Tags: php, session, cakephp, nginx, session-variables

I am working session topic using `cakephp` application in Nginx server:

When I am uploading large files which takes more than an hour, Session is timed out and once the upload percentage reaches to 100% page is refreshing and showing the login page.  I am new to this session concept.

Tried adding session start with cookie_lifetime in application:

```
session_start([
  'cookie_lifetime' => 86400,
]);
```

Modified php.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize = 3072M
post_max_size = 3072M
session.gc_maxlifetime = 6144
```

How to make current session alive and access stored values in session? How to increase session timeout?

Comment: Take a see here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311320/how-to-change-the-session-timeout-in-php

Comment: is `max_execution_time` set correctly ?

Comment: Yes, max_execution_time is set to 30000

Answer (score 0):

**Set the PHP time limit to 60 minutes**

```
set_time_limit(3600);
ini_set('set_time_limit', '3600');
```

**Set PHP max execution time**

```
ini_set('max_execution_time',3600);
```

**Set PHP max input time**

```
ini_set('max_input_time','200')
```

**Set the session lifetime**

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',84000);
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime',84000);
```

**Set the memory limit**

```
ini_set('memory_limit','512M');
```

**Setting maximum filesize**

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '3072M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '3072M');
```

Comment: Thankyou. I added all parameters but no result. Still the issue remains same.

Comment: @Dollyh I updated my answer, copy the code and try again.

Comment: You should be doing something wrong. I personally have this and it works fine for me. On my website, movies and big clips are being uploaded. Try editing the size and time values to your own. ( Make them bigger )

Comment: Okay, I will try out again. In my case uploads will go for more than 2 hours depends on the client bandwidth. According to this I increased the values. For quick check I made session maxlifetime to 1 min and checked still it shows  maxlife time is 1 hour. But when I checked through phpinfo(); it showed updated values.

Comment: Are you using ini_set or updating values from the .ini file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155513/discussion-between-dollyh-and-mr-pro-pop).