# PHP session not expiring

Tags: php, session

So I have been trying to work with session but it seems my code is not working.
My session_start() function when creating session is inside of an if statement after validating login from server, not at the start of PHP.
The following are my codes:

```
//Creating sessions
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['last_active'] = time();

        $_SESSION['username'] = 
        $logged_user;

        //redirecting from login page to any page.
        //refresh sets the redirect time.
        header("Refresh: 3; URL=redirect_after_login.php");
```

The following is the code after redirect:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['last_active']) && (time() - $_SESSION['last_active'])>10)
{
/*
##This if statement checks if the last activity session is set or not
##Then checks if the time is more than 10 minutes.
*/
session_destroy();
header('Location = login.php');}
```

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311320/how-to-change-the-session-timeout-in-php

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem with this code. Now I know why my code was not working... 
In the second code snippet I used `header('Location = login.php');` this is wrong.
header uses colon(:) not an equal (=) sign. Finally today when I was reviewing my code I saw this error. So the code should be `header('Location:login.php');`.