# Apache2 PHP - How to extend session timeout

Tags: php, apache2

I have an Apache2 web server with PHP running on my Raspberry Pi and I'm using sessions for storing the user's ID when they log in. I noticed that when the browser closes, the session is destroyed. How do I make the session last longer (ideally forever until they log out)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the session timeout in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311320/how-to-change-the-session-timeout-in-php)

Comment: Also, your browser could be destroying the PHPSESSID cookie on close, incognito does that for example

Comment: For that you need to edit system files and it is quite a boring task. Why don't you just store data as cookie and retrive them anytime you want? It's simple and easy.

Comment: Can users manually put cookies into their browser? That's what I was worried about.

Comment: My answer did solve your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a special setting of [session_start()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php#example-6004) provided by `PHP 7.0`... with the following setting the `session` expires after `1 day` (`86400` seconds)... you can adjust this value as you want... even if you close the browser the `session` persists, to terminate your `session` you'll have to invoke [session_destroy()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php)...

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
  if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '7.0.0') >= 0) {
    session_start(['cookie_lifetime' => 86400,]);
  } else {
    session_start();
  }
}
```

I hope this helps.