# making user redirect if not logged in using php sessions

Tags: php

I am beginner in web development and i am creating my first project. I am using XAMPP, for my php files. I have basically created **app.php**, **sigin.php**. So in order to prevent user from directly access my **app.php** i am using session variables in php. Hence i added the following PHP code just before my **app.php**.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['loginstatus'])) {
        header('location:./login.php');
        die();
    }
?>
```

And i am setting my session variables in my **signin.php** like the following:

```
if($user['username'] == $username && $user['password'] == $password) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['loginstatus'] = 'success';

        echo "success!";

        header('location:../app.php');
 }
```

Now i tried accessing my **app.php** without login, i am still able to access **app.php**. To check where is the issue i cleared my browser history and cookies, then i tried accessing **app.php**, then surprisingly it worked i was actually redirected to login page, but as soon as i do first succesfull login, and logout and again try to access **app.php** without login, i was again able to access **app.php** without login.

Now for some reason i feel that my browser is saving session variables too, So to check that i wrote a small piece of code and pasted in my **app.php**:

```
<?php
    var_dump($_SESSION['loginstatus']);
?>
```

after first successful login my **$_SESSION['loginstatus']** is always set to **successful**. Now as i said i am a beginner, what i learnt is session are stored in server side. So i am totally confused regarding this.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Any modern [development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in, and there are [authentication libraries](http://phprbac.net/) you can use. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: Once set, unless you explicitly clear your session or otherwise change that value it will stay set. `$_SESSION` should be bound to a cookie, so if you cleared them it *should* be gone, but perhaps you didn't clear out the right ones.

Comment: @tadman where to clear the session, i am doing session_destroy() in logout.php file.

Comment: If this is just academic code for learning then you've got a lot of learning to do so I hope you're ready for that. If instead your goal is to make a production site then this is the wrong way to go about doing it, you're making huge mistakes here that must be avoided. If you want to learn about how to implement an authentication system start by studying how others work, and of course [learn about the threats you need to protect against](https://owasp.org/www-project-cheat-sheets/).

Comment: I am just doing it for learning purpose, not for production, or any serious development.

Answer (score 1):

There is a cookie in your webbrowser "phpsessid" wich stores the id of the Session on the server.
In normal cases you destroy the Session, at logout.

session_unset(); to unset all session variables

session_destroy(); destroys the session

The Session will timeout after time X. You can change it, described here -> [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311320/how-to-change-the-session-timeout-in-php)

So if you have a cookie in your Browser with a valid id of a not-timeouted Session you will always be able to log in.

Comment: though it didn't workout, but your answer has bunch of informational stuff.+1 for your answer

Answer (score 0):

So basically, going to browser setting > privacy and security > more > **pre-load pages for faster browsing and searching**

I just disabled this default setting from chrome, and it started working as expected.