# PHP Because of my new hosting firm my sessions started to end in half an hour idle time. How to change it with code (without php.ini or htaccess)

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, expired-sessions

[image]checked this link: [How to change the session timeout in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311320/how-to-change-the-session-timeout-in-php)
but couldn't solve the issue...

```
> > $twenty_days = 60 \* 24 \* 20; // 20 days in minutes

session_cache_expire($twenty_days);

session_start();
```

AND TRIED

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', xxx);

ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', xxx);
```

EDIT: Solved with this:

```
session_set_cookie_params('604800', '/', null, true, true);

// Start the session
session_start(); }
```

Comment: 1st user comment on PHP site, `"The manual probably doesn't stress this enough:
** This has nothing to do with lifetime of a session **"`

Comment: If sessions are genuinely expiring after 30 mins, look into using `session_set_cookie_params` before `session_start`.

Comment: which hosting firm?

Comment: do i delete this question, or how to set your answer as accepted answer?

Comment: @YelLOW I've converted my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`session_set_cookie_params`](https://www.php.net/session_set_cookie_params) can be used to set session cookie expiration (and other settings) if your host is setting a `session.cookie_lifetime` value you don't like.

Call it with your desired settings *before* `session_start()`.

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', null, true, true); // expire session when browser closes
session_set_cookie_params(86400, '/', null, true, true); // one day lifetime
session_start();
```