# Session dying after using session_regenerate_id(true)

Tags: php, session-cookies

I followed a tutorial and no matter how many times I check this code, I can't get it to work long term. Upon login the session starts,but after the set interval time when it should reset (`60* 30`), the session gets destroyed and the user is logged out.

I've shortened the time to test this, setting the time to `60 * 3` and continuously refreshing the page every 30 seconds.

The session also died after 3 minutes, despite that page being the only one refreshed and the require being at the top of the page (`require_once 'includes/config_session.inc.php';`)

How can I prevent the session from dying and keep the user logged in after using `session_regenerate_id(true)`?

Here is the code for my config_session.inc.php

```
<?php

ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 1);

session_set_cookie_params([
   'lifetime' => 1800, 
    'domain' => 'www.snoozelings.com',
    'path' => '/',
    'secure' => true,
    'httponly' => true
]);

session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['last_regeneration'])) {
        regenerate_session_id_loggedin();
    } else {
        $interval = 60 * 30;
        if (time() - $_SESSION['last_regeneration'] >= $interval) {
            regenerate_session_id_loggedin();
        }
    }
} else {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['last_regeneration'])) {
        regenerate_session_id();
    } else {
        $interval = 60 * 30;
        if (time() - $_SESSION['last_regeneration'] >= $interval) {
            regenerate_session_id();
        }
    }
}
function regenerate_session_id() {
    session_regenerate_id(true);
    $_SESSION['last_regeneration'] = time();
}

function regenerate_session_id_loggedin() {
    session_regenerate_id(true);
    
    $userID = $_SESSION["user_id"];
    
    $newSessionId = session_create_id();
    $sessionId = $newSessionId . "_" . $userID;
    session_id($sessionId);
    
    $_SESSION['last_regeneration'] = time();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the session timeout in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311320/how-to-change-the-session-timeout-in-php)

Comment: No. I can extend the interval to make the session last longer. That isn't the issue. The issue is that after 30 minutes it's supposed to make a new session, and it isn't. It's just dying without creating the new session.

Comment: The default max lifetime is [24 minutes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) (which can be verified when running `<?php phpinfo();`). If you can't increase the limit I'd recommend to lower your setting from 30 to 20

Comment: Like I said, I tried setting it to only 3 minutes and the problem still happened.

Comment: Are you testing this on a mobile network or WiFi? [reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php)

Comment: Wifi network on desktop computer (chrome)

Comment: According to the warning on the documentation, that could be the problem

Comment: Removing the true seemed to fix it for me but I know that's really unsecure. But I don't know how to fix it otherwise :(

Comment: The only suggestions I could find about this is not using the default PHP session mechanism but resort to another session management system, e.g. [symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/session.html) (which can actually be used stand-alone). But maybe someone else will pass by with a solution.

Comment: Is it really necessary to use `regenerate_session_id_loggedin()` and create your own custom session ID? As warned in the docs, this is also more than likely the result of a race condition on the browser considering you are immediately deleting the old session without properly migrating it across to the new session.

Comment: Looks like an X-Y problem to me. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the PHP's session COOKIE not being refreshed upon each request or when we are calling the `session_start` function.

The session COOKIE is being created once when we first call the `session_start` and then it is left as is.

The logic behind this is that by default the `session.cookie_lifetime` param has a value of `0`, meaning `"until the browser is closed."`
[see: PHP docs > Session configuration](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime).

You can also read the following [bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=77251) which describes exactly this "issue". One key point to keep from the comments there, is that if session cookie is not cleared upon browser closer (or session end), when a user, same or worse another one, reopens the browser on the same page, it will have kept the session!

Having said that, you can manually update the session COOKIE when needed. In your sample code that would be in the `regenerate_session_id_loggedin()` function since, you want to keep session for logged-in users.

So you can add the following at the end of the function:

```php
/**
 * Renew the time left until this session times out.
 * If we do not do this, the session will time out based on the 
 * time when it was created rather than when it was last used.
 * @see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php#100657
 */
if(isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
    setcookie(
        session_name(),
        session_id(),
        time() + (60 * 30),
       '/',
        'www.snoozelings.com',
        true,
        true
    );
}
```

That should fix the timeout problem.

---

As a **side note** (irrelevant to the timeout), from the docs for the [session_regenerate_id](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php), you may also need to change your logic for creating a custom session ID. There is an example in the docs page above that suggest the following steps:

1. Save and close current session via `session_commit()`
2. Set new session ID via `session_id('YOUR_CUSTOM_ID')`
3. Disable `use_strict_mode`
4. Start session via `session_start()`, which will have the newly defined ID.
5. Enable `use_strict_mode`

like so:

```php
// inside of your regenerate_session_id_loggedin
$newSessionId = session_create_id();

// Customize session ID for current USER.
$sessionId = $newSessionId . "_" . $userID;

// Write and close current session;
session_commit();

// Start session with new session ID
session_id($sessionId);
ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 0);
session_start();
ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 1);
// ... rest of your code.
```

Also note, that you call `session_regenerate_id` which renews the session ID and then you create and assign a new one.
Furthermore, the `session_regenerate_id` is being called for all users regardless of their logged-in status, which is something you may or may not want.

---

And a **second note** (this too is irrelevant to the timeout): You can make some refactoring to your code in order to not repeat some logic. e.g.:

```php
<?php

ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 1);

// Init Session config vars.
$sessionCookieLifetime = 60 * 30;

$mySessionCookieParams = [
    'lifetime' => $sessionCookieLifetime, 
    'domain' => 'www.snoozelings.com',
    'path' => '/',
    'secure' => true,
    'httponly' => true
];

session_set_cookie_params($mySessionCookieParams);

session_start();

if ( ! isset($_SESSION['last_regeneration']) ) {
    regenerateSessionByUserStatus();
} else {
    if (time() - $_SESSION['last_regeneration'] >= $sessionCookieLifetime) {
        regenerateSessionByUserStatus();
    }
}

function regenerateSessionByUserStatus() {
    session_regenerate_id(true);
    
    if (isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
        $userID = $_SESSION["user_id"];

        $newSessionId = session_create_id();
        $sessionId = $newSessionId . "_" . $userID;
        session_id($sessionId);

        /**
         * Renew the time left until this session times out.
         * If we do not do this, the session will time out based on the 
         * time when it was created rather than when it was last used.
         * @see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php#100657
         */
        if(isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
            setcookie(
                session_name(), 
                session_id(), 
                time() + $sessionCookieLifetime, 
                $mySessionCookieParams['path'], 
                $mySessionCookieParams['domain'], 
                $mySessionCookieParams['secure'], 
                $mySessionCookieParams['httponly']
            );
        }
    }

    $_SESSION['last_regeneration'] = time();
}
```